# How to extract information and transform true to 1?

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I got this code :

```
foreach($data['matches'] as $matches){
$win += $matches['participants'][0]['stats']['winner'];
if ($win == true){
$winner+= '1';
}
}
```

This code extract information from an API, and what I want is how much the value "true" is in the API, soo I've tried to convert "true" to 1, but still not working well.
In the api there are 8 "true" but when I've tried to print `$winner` I got just 2.

What to do please to correct the code ?

Comment: 1. Change `$win +=` to `$win =` 2. Use this: `if ($win == true) $winner++;` 3. Make sure `$winner` is initialized before the loop; Does that do the trick?

Comment: I've done the 3 steps and i got just "1" this time, still not working well.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($matches['participants'][0]['stats']['winner']);` ?

Comment: output : `bool(false) bool(false) bool(true) bool(false) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(false) bool(true) bool(true) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)`

Comment: Did you tried it with this: `$winner = 0; foreach($data["matches"] as $matches){if($matches['participants'][0]['stats']['winner'] === true) $winner++;} echo $winner;` ?

Comment: I think it will works. Check the answer.

Comment: wow and why did you wrote first that it doesn't worked?! I wrote that 15min ago!

Comment: sorry my bad, i didnt understand that well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make  `$win = $matches['participants'][0]['stats']['winner'];` and then if `$win` is equal to `true` increment `$winner`.

```
$winner = 0;

foreach($data['matches'] as $matches){
$win = $matches['participants'][0]['stats']['winner'];
if ($win == true) {
$winner++;
}
}
```

Comment: @vladeuurs255s the code works for you? I don't know why the people vote down, they are sicks?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer *@vladeuurs255s if you want, you can upvote my answer ;-)* Should that be begging for rep? If not there is a tool tip if you hover over the upV arrow which says: `This answer is helpful` and NOT `Just upV this answer`

Comment: @Rizier123 there are people who do not know the operation of that button, just I saw that vladeuurs255s had never voted. It was also a way to teach him to do it, but apparently this has upset you. Or have I done something wrong? In this case help me because I am on this site also learning, even English that is not my language.